# Using Camera 2 SurfaceView, how can I achieve a blur preview as below

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview, android-camera2

How can I achieve below view to capture picture

[image]

Comment: there are 2 separate questions in your question. 1) How to blur view. 2) how to make part of view transparent. Solve them separately.

Comment: @VladMatvienko Yes you may be correct, but for generic activity views I am able to achieve blur result, this is a case for camera input displayed on a Surface view, for which I have no clue of how to do it.

Comment: but how does `SurfaceView` differ from `generic view`? What is the problem?

Comment: @Shashwat did you find a solution on how to blur the view?